# How to update the Liferay 7.2 form data

Tags: jsp, liferay

I am using mysql to store the Liferay repository. I have a form that is stored on a table (ddmcontent) which I have copied to a second database (same table name) for further processing.
I need someone to review this data submitted by the user.  The form data is in json format.
What is the best way to create a dxp page where this data can be displayed and someone with admin can modify it as needed?
I have done rest api before however that is directly on the actual form table, not sure how I pull the data from a second/alternative table?
2. Is simple jsp and jdbc stand alone solution will work here or can I leverage the liferay functionality?
thank you for your guidance in advance

Comment: you can make workflow for form entries

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay, [you ***do not think*** in terms of database tables](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/understanding-liferay-s-database) - specifically not for those tables that Liferay uses internally. Period!

For Liferay Forms, you can subject them to a workflow (as Pratik mentions in a comment), and the platform will take care of their status during the Workflow process. If you want to process this outside of the regular workflow, use the API to access the data, not SQL.

As you've already found the table, the API names are very similar, so you're looking for anything starting with `DDM` as a starting point.

Comment: I understand you are talking about ddm services to read data, however I was looking for a complete example of updating this data from json format

Comment: well, you *really* shouldn't think in terms of database - which you did. And it doesn't matter what for. So I stand by my answer. With regards to "asking for a complete example": I don't read that out of your question, and such a broad question would easily be off-topic for stackoverflow (see [help/on-topic])